# SQL table association

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have 3 database tables and I need to normalize them. The association between tables like this:

Tables:
1. question
2. answers
3. comments

- (question can contain many answers and many comments)
- (answers can contains many comments)

I know I could use questions and answers in one table and then I solve the problem, but I want to use it this way, so what's the best way to associate 'comments' with 'questions' and 'answers'?

I tried to put question id and answer id into the table of comments and use only one of them for each row, is this right? this way I can use them in php script but I don't know if there is another better way because that I asked.

Thank you.

Comment: Worth a look at how SO does it http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: @ConradFrix this is a nice contribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would set them up as follows:

```
Posts (both Questions and Answers would be types of "Posts"):
Post_ID
[Fields Common to Posts, e.g. "Post_Content", "Poster_ID", "Post_TimeStamp" etc.]

Questions:
Question_ID
Post_ID
[Question-specific fields, e.g. "Question_Title"]

Answers:
Answer_ID
Post_ID
[Answer-specific fields]

Comments:
Comment_ID
Post_ID
[Comment fields]
```

The main idea of having a seperate Posts table is to normalize your database, and allow for a logical structure for comments to point to both.  Like APC commented, it also gives you a good setup for developing your site/database going into the future (when you might want other types of commentable "Posts."

While the enum method listed below would work, it's not good database design.  In general, I would suggest only using ENUMs when you're representing a real world list of items.. not for organizing your database structure.

Comment: +1 - the canonical solution.  This solution has the distinct advantage that it is relatively painless to add new types of Posts, should the need arise.  I agree it is unlikely in this specific example, but if we were discussing PERSONS rather than POSTS the advantages would be clearer.

Comment: Good answer there.. Not that I'm criticizing your answer. Just curious behind the rationale of having Questions table having Question_ID as well as Post_ID and the like ? What do you think would be common to posts and specific to questions ? Thanks!

Comment: Updated the post with an explanation as well as example fields

Answer (score 0):

Use an extra `type` field in the `comments` table which holds `"question"` or `"answer"` for a *polymorphic association*. Queries then just include that field:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `type` = 'question' AND `foreign_key` = 42
```

Comment: We cannot define a foreign key constraint against two tables, so there could be no enforcement of the values in that column.  (Assuming we're using InnoDB as our engine, otherwise the point is moot).

Comment: I already need to save ids, so I'll got non-benefit for adding new column. think about it like here in stackoverflow, I guess they use it like what @babonk said.